# How does buoyant force formula work if it got nothing to doi with the dencity of the object?

Tags: forces, buoyancy

[image: google search for the formula of buoyant force]

Google tell me the formula for buoyant force is Fb = -pgV Where Fb is buoyant force and p is fuid dencity , g is gravity index, V is fuid volume which I suppose is just like the volume of the object. But with that formula isn't the buoyant force of a block of iron bigger than a piece if wood?
because a block of iron have bigger volume.

Comment: Why would a block of iron necessarily have a bigger volume than a piece of wood? It has greater *density* but this is not relevant for the buoyant force.

Comment: Your question lacks context if you are somehow talking about two different volume pieces of material, and yes if a block of iron had more volume it's boyant force would be larger....but you'd still have to take into account each objects gravitational force which is larger for the iron.

Comment: I mean for example , here is a block of iron with volume of 10m³ and here is a piece of wood with volume of 1³ with the formula I suppose the bouyant force of the block of iron will be 1000*9.8*10³=9800000 and for the wood I suppose it will be 1000*9.8*1³=9800, if an iron got bigger buoyant force than the piece of wood why the iron sink and the wood floot?

Comment: Again try calculating the weight of each block too, you'll find that the irons weight is much larger than it's boyant force.

Comment: oh so I acually need to do this: the weight of the object - pgV

Comment: V is the weight of the volume of water displaced by the object. It is only the volume of the object if the object is totally immersed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula refers to the density of the fluid and the volume of fluid displaced by the solid object.  The buoyant force on a block of iron in water is the same as the buoyant force on a block of wood in water, if the blocks are fully submerged and have the same volume.  However, the block of iron sinks because its weight is greater than the buoyant force, whereas the block of wood floats because its weight is less than the buoyant force.

I've assumed the wood is fully submerged.  Obviously it will soon rise to the surface.  Once it is floating, it will displace less water than when it was submerged.  How much less?  Enough so that the buoyant force equals the wood's weight.